# Initialize context for use getSystemService

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to use this code in my class

```
public class ADialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {

    public ADialog(Context arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(arg0);
        final View Viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

Context mContext;
        audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


        setTitle("Dialog");
        setView(Viewlayout);

        setNeutralButton("Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });

        create();
        show();
    }
}
```

if I try to initialize putting the Context getApplicationContext () eclipse tells me

The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type ADialog

So, how to solve this problem?

LOGCAT

> 11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application 11-17 18:40:05.079:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) 11-17 18:40:05.079:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   com.packagename.Dialog.(Dialog.java:236) 11-17 18:40:05.079:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   com.packagename.Settings$1.onPreferenceClick(Settings.java:59) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:952) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:297)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-17 18:40:05.079:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 11-17 18:40:05.079:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>   11-17 18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 11-17
>   18:40:05.079: E/AndroidRuntime(16392):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line like this

```
Context mContext;
```

into

```
Context mContext=arg0;
```

OR call audio manager like this..

```
 audioManager = (AudioManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Crash. I've posted the logcat. The line correspond at show();

Comment: its because need you need to send Activity object instead of Context object from your activity like Activity.this